# Replacing destination using NavGraph (transaction when using app:popUpTo)

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

We need to implement a state-machine driven navigation, where the currently shown screen depends on current state. As such, our approach so far has been to use global actions and navigate to the right screen whenever the state changes. On first look, everything seemed to work great, however, we've started noticing some weird behaviours when using the `app:popUpTo` attribute on the actions.

In our concrete case, we have 2 sub nav graphs (let's call them `NG1` and `NG2`), where `NG2` is state-machine driven. Let's say we're in screen `A` in `NG1` and then we navigate to `NG2`, which adds screen `B`. We now have 2 options:

1. If we navigate to screen `C` (in `NG2`) using an action with `app:popUpTo="@+id/NG2"` (effectively aiming to replace `B` with `C`), then, **sometimes**, Fragment `A` briefly starts (`onStart`) for a few tens of milliseconds and then stops, before starting `C`. So instead of `B -> C`, we get `B -> A -> C`. It seems that an action with a `popUpTo`, is not transactional.
2. If we navigate to screen `C` (in `NG2`) using an action without `app:popUpTo="@+id/NG2"`, screen `A` does not start, but `B` is left in the back stack. As such, if screen `B` needs to be shown again, we end up with a backstack looking like `A / B / C / B`, which is not what we're aiming for.

Of course, the behaviour we're looking for is the one attempted in 1, where we can move from a screen `X` to a screen `Y` to a screen `Z`, with popping `Y`, but not briefly starting `X`. Is there anything we're doing wrong or is it a bug in the `android-navigation` component?

---

I'm also adding some logs, showing actual logs that I've just replicated (timestamps are actual):

```
// Here we navigate from A to B
2020-03-09 19:14:14.999 BaseAppNavigator: Navigating to directions: com.example.app:id/toNavGraph2
2020-03-09 19:14:15.006 BaseAppNavigator.OnDestinationChangedListener: Navigation destination changed: com.example.app:id/fragmentB
2020-03-09 19:14:15.007 BaseAppNavigator.OnDestinationChangedListener: Active navigation graph changed to: com.example.app:id/navGraph2
2020-03-09 19:14:15.235 BaseViewModelFragment: OnStart: FragmentB
2020-03-09 19:14:15.247 BaseViewModelFragment: OnStop: FragmentA

// Here we trigger navigate from B to C, with a destination with popUpTo="navGraph2"
2020-03-09 19:14:56.422 BaseAppNavigator: Navigating to directions: com.example.app:id/toFragmentC
2020-03-09 19:14:56.430 BaseAppNavigator.OnDestinationChangedListener: Navigation destination changed: com.example.app:id/fragmentC
2020-03-09 19:14:56.516 BaseViewModelFragment: OnStart: FragmentA
2020-03-09 19:14:56.529 BaseViewModelFragment: OnStop: FragmentB
2020-03-09 19:14:56.537 BaseViewModelFragment: OnDestroy: FragmentB
2020-03-09 19:14:56.580 BaseViewModelFragment: OnStart: FragmentC
2020-03-09 19:14:56.613 BaseViewModelFragment: OnStop: FragmentA
```

with the following action:

```
<action
      android:id="@+id/toFragmentC"
      app:destination="@id/fragmentC"
      app:popUpTo="@+id/NavGraph2" />
```

Comment: Do any of your Fragments use `postponeEnterTransition()`?

Comment: No, we're not using any transitions so far on this.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, any more updates on this? In short, it seems the problem stems from the fact that the BackStack pop is not executed in the same transaction as the adding of the new fragment. Are there any plans to tackle this at any point?

Comment: Unfortunately this issue is still active. Furthermore, I've begun noticing it in scenarios involving simple nav graphs (without sub nav graphs): If the back stack looks like A, B, when attempting to navigate from B to C with `popUpTo=A`, instead of C starting while B is stopping, A starts for a short amount of time, before starting C.

Comment: Navigation controls none of this behavior, it is all dependent on what version of Fragments you are using. I'd make sure you're using the latest Fragment 1.3.0-rc02 first